# How to avoid Shell script Sed modifying password variable contents

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

When i am trying to sed as below

```
sed -e 's,</Context>,<Resource name="ABC"  password="'"$DB_PASS"'"/>\n&,' -i /path
```

sed is truncating backslash.

For example

```
DB_PASS='1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)[{]}\|'
```

O/p is

```
<Resource name="jdbc/KARDB" 
 password=""1!2@3#4$5%6^7</Context>8*9(0)[{]}|""/> </Context>
```

if my `DB_PASS` contains backslash, &, single quote double quote anyother spl characters i dont want sed to change password contents. but substitute as it is.

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: Use code tags to make your post readable. Select the text you like code around an click `{}` above the post.

Comment: `sed` is wrong tool for xml editing

Comment: can you also add the file you are trying to parse

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem you run into is that your password contains `&`, which in the replacement part of an `s` command refers to the matched text.

As has become a litany of mine, it is generally not a good idea to substitute shell variables into sed code precisely for reasons like these: sed cannot differentiate between code and your data. This is one of the more harmless things that could go wrong; imagine what GNU sed would have done if someone had entered a password like `rm -Rf /,e #`.

A direct replacement with GNU awk (it has to be gawk because `RT` is GNU-specific) could be

```
DB_PASS="$DB_PASS" gawk -v RS='</Context>' '{ printf $0; if(RT == RS) { print "<Resource name=\"jdbc/KARDB\" password=\"" ENVIRON["DB_PASS"] "\"/>" } printf RT }'
```

The usual `-v dbpass="$DB_PASS"` trick does not work here because you don't even want escape sequences interpreted, so we forcefully add `DB_PASS` to `awk`'s environment and take it from there. Add `-i inplace` to awk's options if you want the file to be changed in place and you have GNU awk 4.1.0 or later, although I usually use `cp file file~; awk ... file~ > file` to have a backup in case things go wrong.

There's a problem, however: how do you handle `"` in passwords? Might be a good idea to do something like `dbpass = ENVIRON["DB_PASS"]; gsub(/"/, "&quot;", dbpass);` and use `dbpass` in the output. And the same for all other critical characters, such as `<` and `>`.

Since you appear to be parsing XML data, it would be better to use an XML-based tool, so that you don't run into problems when the `Context` tag is empty and written as `<Context/>`, and to avoid the above problem (which could be a rather big one). For example, with xmlstarlet you could do something like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s '//Context' -t elem -n Resource -i '//Context/Resource[not(@name)]' -t attr -n name -v 'jdbc/KARDB' -i '//Context/Resource[@name="jdbc/KARDB"]' -t attr -n password -v "$DB_PASS"
```

This consists of three steps:

```
-s '//Context' -t elem -n Resource
```

inserts an empty `Resource` subnode under every `Context` node (this is fine if there's only one; otherwise you might want to specify it in more detail)

```
-i '//Context/Resource[not(@name)]' -t attr -n name -v 'jdbc/KARDB'
```

inserts an attribute `name="jdbc/KARDB"` in every `Context/Resource` node that has no name (which is hopefully only the one we just inserted), and

```
-i '//Context/Resource[@name="jdbc/KARDB"]' -t attr -n password -v "$DB_PASS"
```

inserts a `password` attribute with the value of `$DB_PASS` (properly quoted) in every `Resource` node under a `Context` node whose `name` attribute has the value `jdbc/KARDB` (again, this should be only the node we just inserted). For a more perfect solution that inserts the whole node in one go, you'll want to take a closer look at xslt, but if you were happy with the original sed approach, none of the shortcomings of this approach should be a problem.

Comment: I have used the suggestion from the link http://backreference.org/2009/12/09/using-shell-variables-in-sed/                   Yet to test if " works with the suggestion

Comment: Oh, wow. On the list of brittle hackery, the article behind that link ranks somewhere between Perl lists and unsanitized GET parameters in SQL queries. If you're really not worried about special XML characters and like sed so much that you don't want to consider using awk, at least make sed treat the password as data. `(echo '1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)[{]}\|'; cat foo.xml) | sed '1 {h;d}; /<\/Context>/ { G; s,\(.*\)\(</Context>.*\)\n\(.*\),\1<Resource name="jdbc/KARDB" password="\3"/>\2, }'` is not completely insane, at least.